# How can i remove the white border of grub?

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, grub, arch-linux

Ive seen the [grub menu](https://cdn.fedoramagazine.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/imageedit_2_9587462827.png) for fedora 35 (its clean, you only see the menu).
On my arch install there is [this](https://averagelinuxuser.com/assets/images/posts/2017-08-02-dual-boot-arch-linux-with-another-linux/Grub_menu.jpeg) border around the menu. I used the 'stock' grub menu on both distros, so I havent changed any cosmetics.

How can I remove it? Is it a design choice built into the binary or is it a default setting in a config file?

Comment: You might try Grub Customizer, https://itsfoss.com/customize-grub-linux/ . **Caveat:** setting too large a font or other mistake could hide the menu!

Comment: is that something you cannot tweak manually? i hate gui tools. but ill take a look